# Ubuntu 20.04 is not booting in my MacBook Air

Tags: boot, partitioning, mac

This is my situation. I have a MacBook Air with 128 GB of storage, so I decided to install Ubuntu on an external hard drive with 1TB of free storage. I booted a USB to install and started using Ubuntu normally for a couple of days. Then I switched to MacOS for three days or so, and inside DiskUtility tried partitioning my HDD which already had Ubuntu because I wanted to resize the partition. I messed it up and when I tried booting Ubuntu it gave me an error. So I erased my Hard Drive and tried reinstalling Ubuntu, but now every time I try booting from it the screen goes black, and after some time a GNU Grub menu appears which gives me some options like Ubuntu, Advanced settings, Memory Test (memtest86+) and Memory Test (memtest86+, serial console 115200). I have already tried editing the quiet splash, writing nomodeset after it but nothing happens. Maybe I broke in some way the Efi boot system, but I am just a beginner so I really don't know

Comment: Update: I have just read it may have been that I deleted my EFI system partition, and when I reinstalled Ubuntu I never created a partition with a boot flag. Could that be it?